# Office 365 API throwing 500 on /me/calendars endpoint

Tags: ruby, rest, azure, office365

Screenshot: http://take.ms/MWwbv

Endpoint: https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendars

We're providing an access token in the headers of the request.  It's been working for weeks and just broke with this error today.

=== Start Error Message ===

Server Error in '/API' Application.

The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.CallContext.DisposeOwaFields() +0
   Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.CallContext.Dispose(Boolean isDisposing) +864
   Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataContext.InternalDispose(Boolean disposing) +82
   Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.DisposeTrackableBase.Dispose() +80
   Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.DisposeTrackableBase.Dispose() +80
   Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.HttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +24
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +282

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36215

=== End Error Message ===

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a server issue. I'll get this to the right folks.

**UPDATE**: The fix is rolling out now, so hopefully this should start clearing up for you.

Comment: Please post a followup here when this is to be resolved.  I'm getting this on /me/messages

Comment: Will do. Engineers investigating now.