# Constructor of type HttpHandler not found using the Office 365 API

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I recently started using the Office 365 API and can now [successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145989/authentication-problems-using-the-office-365-api/34152346#34152346) authenticate and get a token. Now I want to query the user's Exchange for meetings. To do this I run the example query from [here](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet):

```cs
    var client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/2.0"), async () =>
    {
      // Since we have it locally from the Session, just return it here.
      return token;
    });

    var eventResults = await client.Me.Events.OrderByDescending(e => e.Start).Take(10).Select(e => new DisplayEvent(e.Subject, e.Start.ToString(), e.End.ToString())).ExecuteAsync();
    // query: https://outlook.office.com/api/2.0/Me/Events?$orderby=Start%%20desc&$top=10&$select=Subject,Start,End
```

Unfortunately, this returns the following error (500): `Server Error in '/API' Application. Constructor on type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.HttpHandler' not found.`

Googling around, I found some similar errors ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281702/office-365-api-throwing-500-on-me-calendars-endpoint) and [here](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/291738)). It seemed there was an issue with the server at that time. However, as the API is pretty mature, I assume I am doing something wrong, rather than a server error.

**Edit**: Testing the query on https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/ also results in the same error, while the example queries work.

Does someone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a typo in the [.NET getting started](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet) calendar code that uses a bad URI for the constructor of the `OutlookServicesClient` object. That line should read:

```
OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(
  new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"),
```

The sample was missing the `v` in the URI, which was causing the error.

Comment: Thank you Jason for your great help!